# QT LocalSocketError event from async thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple QT program that connects to a socket and sends/receives basic commands. I am trying to run the function `QLocalSocket::connectToServer()` in a `QtConcurrent::run` thread and receive any error events in the main thread.

My problem is that I am getting an error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError'
(Make sure 'QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

This makes sense [according to the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html#errorOccurred). But I can't seem to use the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() and qRegisterMetaType()` correctly.

First, I connect to the error event like so in my `mainwindow.cpp` class:

```
connect(
    server->socket,
    QOverload<QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError>::of(&QLocalSocket::error),
    this,
    &MainWindow::socketError
);
```

Then, I have tried putting in `main.cpp`

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError);
```

and then in my `mainwindow.cpp` class:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError>();
```

This still gives me an error on compile `The type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system`.

I can't seem to find any good info on how to use the given macro and function to register this exact type with QT. Any hints as to how to register this type with the meta-object system?

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. first, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Second, you are trying to connect to `error` which should be `errorOccured`, no?

Comment: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE goes to the header file

Comment: @Xplatforms is correct, I had to move it to a header file instead of in my main.cpp file. Thanks! If you write this as an answer I will accept it